# View Pager 2 Causing Lag

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, webview, lag

I have setup a view pager 2 with 4 fragments each containing a web view (which load an iframe each). The problem is that when the view pager is instantiated, it loads all the web views at the same time, which causes serious amounts of lag on slower android devices. Is there any way to load the webviews in a lazy way or any other way to remove or reduce the lag.

Comment: use viewpager2 and load them only when you open the fragment

Comment: I am using view pager 2, forgot to mention it.  And I am loading the fragments in the `onTabSelected` method of the tab layout (which I am using to drive the VP2)